# Can setup WildFly 18 for automatic restart JVM after crash?

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-18

can I setup WildFly 18 for automatic restart after a JVM crash?

We use the JNI interface for native applications and we has a periodicly crash JVM. Use full-ha and ha modes does't work. Аfter JVM-crash, we should manually start server.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Answer (score 2):

WildFly AS is not able to restart itself after JVM crash. You can't configure this on the application server level.

Operating System should be able to monitor services and restart them after crashes. 
If you are using linux based system, you can utilize systemctl manager. See following:

- [How to configure Systemd for starting WildFly](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-wildfly-on-ubuntu-18-04/#step-4-configure-systemd)
- [General information about Systemd and Systemctl](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units)